# KnockoutJS: Checking if items in nested sortable were reordered

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, nested-sortable, knockout-sortable

The following is a tree displayed as `nestedSortable` using `template` in KnockoutJS.

So far I have a tree that works, but I was not able to find an efficient way to check for the changes caused by mouse dragging.

The solution should allow checking for change events whenever a node is dragged (tracking the changes is necessary for saving or updating the data). It should be able to determine what was changed in the tree.

The attributes of interest would be `id` of the node moved, `id` of new (and original) parent.

How to properly monitor the mouse events, such as mouse drag with this type of sortable?

```js
function Node(data) {
  var self = this;
  typeof data != 'undefined' ? self.id = data.id : self.id = '1';
  self.parent = ko.observable();
  self.children = ko.observableArray();
  self.addNode = function() {
    var child = new Node({
      'id': self.id + '.' + (self.children().length + 1)
    });
    child.parent(self);
    self.children.push(child);
    return child;
  }
};
var tree = new Node();
var child1 = tree.addNode();
var child11 = child1.addNode();
var child12 = child1.addNode();
var child2 = tree.addNode();
var child21 = child2.addNode();
var child3 = tree.addNode();
var viewModel = function() {
  this.tree = ko.observable(tree);
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

$('.sortable')
  .nestedSortable({
    startCollapsed: false
  });
```

```css
ol.sortable,
ol.sortable ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol.sortable {
  margin: 4em 0;
}
.sortable li {
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sortable li div {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable/master/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="dd" data-bind="template: {name:'nodeTemplate', data: tree}"></div>
<script id='nodeTemplate' type='text/html'>
  <div data-bind="text: id"></div>
  </div>
  <ol class="sortable ui-sortable" data-bind="foreach: { data: children, as: 'child' }">
    <li data-bind="template: {name:'nodeTemplate', data: child}, attr: { 'data-id': child.id }">
    </li>
  </ol>
</script>
```

Comment: Woa, you have *a lot* of things going on in your code / we have to go through a lot of code to see what's going on. Can you trim it down to a repro so that it's a minimal repro for exactly one issue?

Comment: I'm doing exactly that, some parts still can be trimmed down

Comment: You have about 30 lines of css, I'd hazard a guess about 90% of them is not needed to demonstrate the issue. I also suggest removing dependencies that are irrelevant (e.g. bootstrap). Etc.

Comment: I took the suggestions, it's acceptable size now.

Comment: Have you looked at a binding handler for sortable? https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: I'm working here with nested-sortable, which may not be compatible, as it is used to create trees

Comment: Whether that handler is compatible or not, you will need to use custom a binding handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a direction. You can use events of the "parent" [Sortable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/).

May be the ["stop"](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) event of the Sortable Widget helps you?

```js
var size = 5;
var navigationItems = {};
navigationItems['id'] = 'list_' + (i + 1);
navigationItems['displayLabel'] = 'list_' + (i + 1);
navigationItems['children'] = new Array(size);
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  navigationItems['children'][i] = {};
  navigationItems['children'][i]['id'] = 'list_' + (i + 1) + ".1";
  navigationItems['children'][i]['displayLabel'] = 'list_' + (i + 1) + ".1";
  navigationItems['children'][i]['children'] = new Array(1);
  navigationItems['children'][i]['children'][0] = {};
  navigationItems['children'][i]['children'][0]['id'] = 'list_' + (i + 1) + ".1.1";
  navigationItems['children'][i]['children'][0]['displayLabel'] = 'list_' + (i + 1) + ".1.1";
  navigationItems['children'][i]['children'][0]['children'] = new Array(0);
};
var viewModel = function() {
  this.tree = ko.observable();
};
var viewModelInstance = new viewModel();
viewModelInstance.tree(navigationItems);
ko.applyBindings(viewModelInstance);

var stopHandler = function(args) {
    var model = ko.dataFor(args.target);
    alert(model.id);
};
$('.sortable')
  .nestedSortable({
    startCollapsed: false,
    stop: stopHandler
  });
```

```css
ol.sortable,
ol.sortable ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol.sortable {
  margin: 4em 0;
}
.sortable li {
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sortable li div {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable/master/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="dd" data-bind="template: {name:'nodeTemplate', data: tree}"></div>
<script id='nodeTemplate' type='text/html'>
  <div data-bind="text: displayLabel"></div>
  </div>
  <ol class="sortable ui-sortable" data-bind="foreach: { data: children, as: 'child' }">
    <!-- ko if: child.children.length > 0 -->
    <li class="mjs-nestedSortable-expanded mjs-nestedSortable-branch" data-bind="template: {name:'nodeTemplate', data: child}, attr: { 'data-id': child.id }">
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: child.children.length == 0 -->
    <li class="mjs-nestedSortable-leaf" data-bind="template: {name:'nodeTemplate', data: child}, attr: { 'data-id': child.id }">
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </ol>
</script>
```

Comment: This would be a part of the solution, I must check if the event data provide enough information to mark it as solved.